# Error 424 - Object Required in Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba

So, I have a simple macro that just clears out specific cells. It worked fine, and then I added a userform that takes input via textbox and I added the last line TextBox1.Value= "" to clear it. Now, clicking the button that runs the macro works, it even clears the box, but then it gives me the 424 error. I'm sure its something basic I'm overlooking, syntax or some closing argument. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub Clear()
'
' Clear Macro
'

'
Range("A1").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("H17").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("H11").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("B1").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("I4").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("K4").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("M4").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("H10").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("H16").Select
Selection.ClearContents
TextBox1.Value = ""
End Sub
Sub notebutton1_Click()
Range("K8").Select
Selection.Copy
End Sub
Sub notebutton2_Click()
Range("K13").Select
Selection.Copy
End Sub
Sub notebutton3_Click()
Range("K18").Select
Selection.Copy
End Sub
```

Comment: How about telling us what line is highlighted when you receive the error?

Comment: Please post the whole code because I think your error is appearing from some where else...

Answer (score 0):

TextBox1.Value = "" should be accompanied with the form it is living in. So for example Userform1.TextBox1.Value = ""